# Close vote queue doesn't load if tag filter is set to [ruby]

Tags: bug, review-queues

I don't get any reviews in the close queue. After displaying "loading item..." for ~30 seconds I get:

[image]

This only seems to occur if I set the tag filter to `[ruby]`, if I clear it it seems to work. If I set it to `[python]` it also seems to work, but if I switch it back to `[ruby]` it errors out again.

This is in both Firefox and Chromium and started about ~2 hours ago (the filter was already set to `[ruby]`). The other queues seem to work fine.

I don't see any errors in my web inspector.

Comment: No repro. Is it still not working for you ?

Comment: Normally that [happens to me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244335/loading-next-item-from-the-close-vote-queue-ends-in-an-error) when I have no reviews for my particular filter. As I have seen other reports about sqlserver timeouts recently I suspect this might be related as well.

Comment: @rene It's magically fixed now, but setting the filter to `[vim]` *does* result in a proper "there are no questions left". error by the way, so not sure if that's the issue...

Comment: Yeah, it depends also on how many you might have skipped, how many other reviewers are active etc. It is a tricky bug and I know Oded looked into it way back but couldn't find a clear root cause so it was left as a quirk. Don't expect a fix not even in 6 to 8 weeks.